# How Android debugging works under the hood?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I understand that there is such thing as Android Debug Bridge and debug is wired through this bridge. It would be good to understand this question deeper.

Comment: This is somewhat like asking how JVM debugging works

Comment: https://www.developer.com/ws/android/how-android-debugging-works.html

Comment: I've seen that article. I thought that SO will benefit if someone will answer this question.